# SQL query : compare strings using concatenate and strcmp

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to compare between two set of strings and want to update status column either as 'same' or 'changed' or 'change'.

i have try to use strcmp and concat as below in the picture, but syntax error keep prompted out.

anyone know how to use strcmp and concat at the same time like below?.

My codes :

```
UPDATE  DMGE1314
SET status2 = 
case 
   when concat(KodDM14,NamaDM14) = CONCAT(KodDM13,NamaDM13) 
        then "NO CHANGED",
   when strcmp(concat(KodDM14,NamaDM14),concat(KodDM13,NamaDM13)) not like "0"  
        then  "spelling different"  else "changed" 
end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: it says : syntax error between at strcmp until not like "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using simple comparisons?

```
UPDATE DMGE1314
    SET status2 = (case when KodDM14 = KodDM13 and NamaDM14 = NamaDM13 
                        then 'NO CHANGED',
                        when KodDM14 is null or NamaDM14 is null or KodDM13 is null or NamaDM13 is null
                        then 'NULL' 
                        else  'SPELLING DIFFERENT'
                   end);
```

Use the built-in operators if you can.  Don't use `strcmp()` to just compare equality.  The purpose is to generate -1, 0, or 1, depending on the ordering of the strings.

Comment: because i thought that i want to update variety of status for an example 'spelling different', 'code change','name change' . so i think that it need to be done by strcmp()

Comment: @SyahirahAR . . . I don't think so.  I can't remember the last time I used `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong comma before the second when

```
UPDATE DMGE1314 
    SET status2 = case 
            when concat(KodDM14,NamaDM14) = CONCAT(KodDM13,NamaDM13) then "NO CHANGED"
            when strcmp(concat(KodDM14,NamaDM14),concat(KodDM13,NamaDM13)) not like "0" 
                    then "spelling different" 
                else "changed" 
          end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot scaisEdge, it worked perfectly.I added the comma and did not know that it makes the syntax error.  looks like i have to be more careful of comma.